# Bottle ssl behind apache

Tags: python, apache, ssl, bottle

Is there any way to deploy a `bottle` application with `SSL` behind `Apache` without using another server such as `CherryPy`? And if so, are there any guides or tutorials to do such a thing?

Comment: Do you require the traffic between Apache and bottle being SSL encrypted?

Comment: no, just the client-server traffic. Im looking to setup HTTPS.